# Debugging error in STL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, stl

I have one big problem with using STL, C++ and Visual Studio. When i use some std or stl functions (in debug compilation) a have some errors some like this `"Incorrect format specifier"`.

but my code are too large for "hand searching" for this error. Maybe one know how to get some help with finding error, some like `__FILE__` & `__LINE__` for assert? Because code of program too large.

Or `try` & `catch` my last hope?...

with respect Alex

Comment: The error message should specify the source file and line number it's associated with...

Comment: @Oli:  I think this one comes from the CRT and does not have file/line info.

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't the compiler give the file & line of all compilation errors?

Comment: @DeadMG:  I think this was a runtime error, not a compilation error.

Comment: doesn't sound like an compiler error, but an assert. "Incorrect format specifier" sounds like a printf-style format string error. ---- @Alex better describe what error you get (or maybe post a screenshot if you feel unsure).

Comment: @peterchen: on the other hand, many compilers check `printf` at compile-time (providing the format is available then), so this could indeed be a compilation error... though given the description I doubt it is.

Comment: Screen: http://s012.radikal.ru/i321/1011/b0/04a03b8059ad.png

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the source code for the STL, what I would do is set a breakpoint at the point where the "Incorrect format specifier" string is located.  Do a grep (eg find in files) for that string, set a breakpoint at each one, run your program and hope for death. :)

Comment: Yes, but i saying what this i have this problem only in other PC (when MSVC not attached to my program).

Comment: @Alex:  Ah, then you're problem is more difficult.  You'll probably need to resort to some combination of sprintf debugging, shotgun debugging, and minidumps, or possibly hooking up WinDbg to the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do status msgs on the console so that you get an idea where the error happens. You can search in this part more detailed with the same technique. Do this as often as you need.
After that you can debug you program and set breakpoints in the 'problem area' and step through it.

EDIT: If you are able to compile the program on linux, you can simply install and run valgrind memcheck. It should print out all errors with line number.

Comment: Only in Windows Platform :( . I know about valgring but... i don't know anything same for Windows only old and stoped projects or commercial

Comment: Because your code is platform dependent or you do not have linux? In last case you could try out a live-cd (e.g. Ubuntu) and install the needed progs during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about try/catch, so I assume it's throwing an exception. If you run your app within the debugger, doesn't it break your program at the point where the uncaught exception is thrown?

EDIT: If you could alternately compile on Linux/g++ it would leave behind a core with a backtrace in that case.

Comment: Sure i see stack and my errors and etc if i run with MSVC (debugging) . But if i run program in other PC (without debugging mode but with debug compilation) i don't see anything , only error line in internal files.

Answer (score 0):

The attached screenshot makes it clear that you hit a runtime assertion, and even offers the option to go directly to the dbugger. This will take you to the faulty callstack.

This message is the default mode of `_CrtDbgReport`. With `_CrtSetReportHook2`, you can run your own code before the error is printed. You might create a minidump, for instance.